# How do I set up Dell Precision 3560?

Tags: dell, intel-cpu

How do I configure and optimize Ubuntu on Dell Precision 3560?

The machine is [certified for Ubuntu](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/202010-28315)

I'm a devops engineer, and I use the machine also for my home studio to record music. I need Wifi, Bluetooth, and a sharp sound chain with real time kernel.

My machine was delivered with Windows, but I know it could have come with Ubuntu 20.04 instead, so I'd be interested to hear of factory tweaks from anyone who got this machine with Ubuntu, especially kernel boot parameters.

Answer (score 2):

## Things I have done

1. Installed UbuntuStudio 20.10, then upgraded to a 21.04 using : `do-release-upgrade -d`
2. Result of `uname -a`

   ```
   5.11.0-13-lowlatency #14-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 19 18:13:56 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
   ```
3. Make sure linux-firmware is installed

   ```
   sudo apt install linux-firmware
   ```
4. The wifi is Intel AX201, relevant data is available at https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi

   The link available on this page to get specific firmware  for that wifi card is totally outdated.
   One should download the one provided at : https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

   For example linux-firmware-20210315.tar.gz, which is the latest at the time I'm writing.

   ```
   wget -O /tmp/linux-firmware-20210315.tar.gz https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/snapshot/linux-firmware-20210315.tar.gz
   cd /tmp/
   tar xfz linux-firmware-20210315.tar.gz
   ```

   At this stage, it's interesting to compare, what is in this archive, with what is already in the system, and what is coming from the outdated link I mentionned :

   ```bsh
   cd /tmp/
   wget -O https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/iwlwifi-qu-48.13675109.0.tgz
   tar xfz iwlwifi-qu-48.13675109.0.tgz
   cd wlwifi-Qu-48.13675109.0
   for i in /tmp/iwlwifi-Qu-48.13675109.0/iwlwifi-Qu-* ;do  d=$(echo $i | cut -d/ -f 4) ;\
       md5sum /lib/firmware/$d ;\
       md5sum /tmp/iwlwifi-Qu-48.13675109.0/$d ;\
       md5sum /tmp/linux-firmware-20210315/$d;echo;\
   done
   ```

   The last command results gives :

   ```
   4b5d629ac5b4a1e117b1ac2b4015cd67  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode
   292972c64b0939e4a9c85260a2605077  /tmp/iwlwifi-Qu-48.13675109.0/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode
   4b5d629ac5b4a1e117b1ac2b4015cd67  /tmp/linux-firmware-20210315/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode

   8123d7111ab0ef605e63d71bcbd6a3a6  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode
   ece6e6651021f5b598ce9b930aa85ee3  /tmp/iwlwifi-Qu-48.13675109.0/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode
   8123d7111ab0ef605e63d71bcbd6a3a6  /tmp/linux-firmware-20210315/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode

   16e59dd2792af9a569a958ff92bd3679  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-48.ucode
   92c163abb627018a36d0b772fc7f9328  /tmp/iwlwifi-Qu-48.13675109.0/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-48.ucode
   16e59dd2792af9a569a958ff92bd3679  /tmp/linux-firmware-20210315/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-48.ucode

   fa192c1c7b6592ed81b58673431ffd72  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-48.ucode
   43b1df97a1ad32b9964df5cb0befdbd7  /tmp/iwlwifi-Qu-48.13675109.0/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-48.ucode
   fa192c1c7b6592ed81b58673431ffd72  /tmp/linux-firmware-20210315/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-48.ucode
   ```

   So now I know I have the latest available, and that the ones coming from iwlifi archive are outdated.

## Problems I still face

1. Unstability of the A2DP Bluetooth sink to my Bluetooth speakers, with appearance in /var/log/syslog of lines like :

   > `hci0: urb 00000000bb1ddbc1 submission failed (90)`
   >
   > `hci0: sending frame failed (-90)`
   >
   > `hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0`

## HW Specs

My hw specs are as follows :

```
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 01)
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a03 (rev 01)
0000:00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
0000:00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 01)
0000:00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 01)
0000:00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a0d (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 01)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
0000:00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 20)
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM (rev 20)
0000:00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 20)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
0000:00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 20)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface (rev 20)
0000:00:17.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
0000:00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0be (rev 20)
0000:00:1d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V (rev 20)
0000:55:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (rev 01)
10000:e0:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a0d3 (rev 20)
10000:e0:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 20)
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5405
10000:e2:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5405
```